# Can I undo a bounty that I accidentally opened for the wrong question?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to endorse a good answer to a question ([Why is "taking a biscuit" a bad thing in the UK?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/70685/why-is-taking-a-biscuit-a-bad-thing-in-the-uk)) that currently has a seemingly bad answer as the accepted answer—but unfortunately I attached the bounty to a different question ([Why is "wong" a bad word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/512708/why-is-wong-a-bad-word)) whose accepted answer is perfectly acceptable. (I have since opened a second bounty on the originally intended question.)

Is there a way to undo the erroneous bounty offer? In particular, I am concerned that the misdirected bounty inaccurately criticizes the accepted answer in that case. Sorry that I can't seem to do simple things correctly.

Comment: I'm okay with forfeiting the points on grounds of my own stupidity, but I'd like to avoid having the accidental bounty hanging around and falsely suggesting my disapproval of the (now formerly) accepted answer and my special admiration for any of the other answers.

Comment: Theoretically, in extreme cases, mods or CMs or someone can reverse the bounty. Maybe they’ll do it here. If they don’t, you’re perfectly welcome to award it to the accepted answer if that’s the one you like best. It’s your “money”, you can give it to whomever you like.

Comment: Have you flagged the post? Better still, visit chat and get hold of a moderator there. On ELL I once had a bounty returned to me when the OP repeatedly edited their question, and removed the reason for my setting up the bounty in the first place.

Comment: Am I reading this right? It seems like a bounty was refunded, but it seems like it was the wrong bounty. The one on the wong question remains, but the one on the biscuit question was removed, whereas this proposal reads as if you wanted the refund to go the other way around.

Comment: All is well now on the bounty front. Thank you, moderators!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderators can refund your bounty. Flag for moderator attention and explain the situation. This is something mods only do in rare cases, but one accidental bounty on the wrong question in a period of years seems like a reasonable ask to me.

Comment: Thanks, ColleenV (and Mari-Lou A). I submitted a custom flag to EL&U moderators several hours ago, at your suggestion. Undoubtedly they have better things to do than to help me undo a stupid but ultimately trivial unforced error. Again, my only regret, besides that I proved once again why I shouldn't be allowed near sharp objects, is that the mistaken bounty makes inaccurate assertions about the question and answers it is attached to. It's ironic, since my motive for opening the intended bounty was to reduce the visibility of what seems to be an inaccurate accepted answer.